# Monitoring nearby WiFi clients

Tags: wifi

I know that a WiFi adapter can scan for active BSSIDs, and that in monitor mode it can scan all unencrypted traffic.

What is the best way to list nearby WiFi *clients* from Python?  I understand that all I might get is a MAC address and the AP it's communicating with, but this is all the data that I need.

Comment: you may just search for "promiscuous mode" https://www.shellvoide.com/python/intercept-and-sniff-live-traffic-data-in-a-network-in-python/

Comment: I'm familiar with promiscuous / monitor mode, but I wasn't aware that `scapy` could inspect the data

Comment: https://www.sans.org/blog/special-request-wireless-client-sniffing-with-scapy/

Answer (score 0):

Check sources for the WPS handshake attacks from the WIFITE package.

I remember it listing clients of all scanned APs, with MACs.

(Needs clients info to force deauth and capture handshake)

---

https://github.com/derv82/wifite/blob/master/wifite.py

---

```
class Client:
    """
        Holds data for a Client (device connected to Access Point/Router)
    """

    def __init__(self, bssid, station, power):
        self.bssid = bssid
        self.station = station
        self.power = power
```

Also

https://gist.github.com/garyconstable/1dca3c32dfd05f0bd15f

---

```
#sniff for client mac's
    de.sniffClients()
```

I don't know python very well, but it's in there.

Comment: remove inaccurate pieces of code via edit